# how to fix "HTTP Status 500- Servlet exception threw an exception"

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

i got this erore and i don't know what's wrong
i just want to check the username & password and then enter a page that shows it login or not

```
package cse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/LogIn"})
public class LogIn extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    User signedInUser = User.login(username, password);

    if(!signedInUser.equals(null)){
         HttpSession s = request.getSession();
         s.setAttribute("signedInKey", (new Date()).getTime() + (new         Random()).nextInt(999999999));
         request.setAttribute("user", signedInUser);
         String url = "http://localhost:8080/java_project/test.jsp";
         response.sendRedirect(url);
    }

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/java_project/notLogIn.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
```

}

and this is the error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling       this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception


 root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
ir.ac.shirazu.cse.LogIn.doPost(LogIn.java:25)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


 root cause 

 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
ir.ac.shirazu.cse.LogIn.doPost(LogIn.java:25)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.40 logs.


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
```

plz help , i really can't understand what's wrong

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session` add required jar in classpath

Comment: You need hibernate-core jar in classpath http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.0.CR1/hibernate-core-3.3.0.CR1.jar

Comment: i used " catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)" but it had syntax error do you know why?

Comment: i add it but it still have the same problem

Comment: how should i use "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session" exactly?

Comment: can you share you User.login(username, password); method ?

Comment: @Andrew-II Edits should be substantial - you should fix all issues in a post when making a suggested edit, not just a single typo. Trivial edits waste reviewers' time and needlessly clutter the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put hibernate3.jar in classpath, specifically in the `WEB-INF/lib` of your deployed application.

In Eclipse IDE, you can do this right-clicking on your project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly.

Click Add... button, select Java Build Path Entries and click Next. Then select the desired jars to be exported to `WEB-INF/lib` and click Finish. Automatically, the source jars will be deployed in the correct path.

I hope this helps. It did for me.

Comment: i have all jars under WEB-INF/lib but my problem is not resloved

Answer (score 1):

remove the jar files and add them again in WEB-INF/lib